# How to write xsd code for below java code

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have following java code:

```
public class SomeType{
    private String firstName;
    private java.util.Date dob;
    private Long someID;
    private Double firstAmount;
    private Double secondAmount;
    private java.util.Date beginDate;
    private java.util.Date endDate;
    // setters and getters
}
```

For above code following is the xml code which is working fine.

```
    <xs:complexType name = "SomeType">
           <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name = "firstName" type = "xsd:String"/>
              <xs:element name = "dob" type = "xsd:date"/>
              <xs:element name = "someID" type = "xsd:long"/>
              <xs:element name = "firstAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
              <xs:element name = "secondAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
              <xs:element name = "beginDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
              <xs:element name = "endDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
           </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
```

Now i have added a following Field in java code:

```
List<Object[]> records = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

I am selecting 4 values(columns) from Database i.e. "firstAmount", "secondAmount", "beginDate" and "endDate" and query.list() is returning me `List<Object[]>`(i.e. Tuples having 4 columns). I am storing all data(after Type Casting and iterating over list of object[]) in "records"(Field). How can I write xsd code for this Field (`List<Object[]`> records) considering that we have to pass this Field to other layer in architecture.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need to replace this piece of XSD

```
<xs:element name = "firstAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
<xs:element name = "secondAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
<xs:element name = "beginDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
<xs:element name = "endDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
```

with a complex type like below

```
  <xs:element name="records">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="field" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name = "firstAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
              <xs:element name = "secondAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
              <xs:element name = "beginDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
              <xs:element name = "endDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:complexType name = "SomeType">
       <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name = "firstName" type = "xsd:String"/>
          <xs:element name = "dob" type = "xsd:date"/>
          <xs:element name = "someID" type = "xsd:long"/>
          <xs:element name = "firstAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
          <xs:element name = "secondAmount" type = "xsd:double"/>
          <xs:element name = "beginDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
          <xs:element name = "endDate" type = "xsd:date"/>
          <xs:element name = "records" type = "recordsType"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name = "recordsType">
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name = "record" type = "recordType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/><!-- a list or 0 or any number of records -->
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name = "recordType">
     <!-- write the internal structure of your record element -->
    </xs:complexType>
```